# HQL in grails with having and max generate unexpected AST node

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

I'd like to do a very simple query.

In SQL is:

```
select * from table group by portfolio_id HAVING max(date)
```

In grails I did something like this:

```
def result = Table.executeQuery("from Table group by portfolio having max(date)")
```

But I got as result an **unexpected AST node**

I have no clue, I read some documentation but I still cannot get it, why it should not work.

Here the error message in more details

```
| Error 2014-01-29 17:20:15,400 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR hql.PARSER - <AST>:1:97: unexpected AST node: max 

| Error 2014-01-29 17:20:15,426 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - QuerySyntaxException occurred when processing request: [GET] /Lumen/Controller unexpected AST node: max near line 1, column 97 [select portfolio.id,date from com.gwm.lumen.Table group by portfolio.id having max(date)].
```

Stacktrace follows:

`Message: unexpected AST node: max near line 1, column 97 [select portfolio.id,date from com.gwm.lumen.Table group by portfolio.id having max(date)]`

Comment: That SQL query works for you if you try it on the db? I would say no, because it's not correct group query. Something like select portfolio_id, max(date) from table group by portfolio_id HAVING max(date) should work

Comment: Hi, I an assure you it works, I tried before posting. The only difference is that in the SQL query I did not do all the inner join that gorm probably would do.

Comment: Interesting.. Any database I know would reject such query. Which db you use? Anyway even if your database accepts such query, it's not correct HQL which is why Grails throws the error. Try something like Table.executeQuery("select portfolio, max(date) from Table group by portfolio having max(date)")

Comment: it's a classic MySql5.5. I tried to specify in the executeQuery the field of aggragation and max, but still same issue

Comment: Post whole exception that you get and a Table class source

Comment: OMG my dear friend edit your question and put it there please!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use aggregate functions [`max()` in this case] in the `having` clause if the underlying database is MySQL.

> SQL functions and aggregate functions are allowed in the having and
>   order by clauses if they are supported by the underlying database
>   (i.e., **not in MySQL**).

@Excerpt taken from [Hibernate Docs on group by clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping).

I am not sure whether the latest MySQL dialects support it.

Comment: thanks a lot, this explains a lot. I just upgraded form 5.5 to 5.6 but still same issue.